# Wordpress wp enqueue style

Tags: css, wordpress

I am writing my first wordpress plugin, and I am stuck. Badly.

I want to include a css file in the admin part of the plugin. But I can`t for some reason. The code I tried (and many variation of it):

```
// Register style sheet.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_styles' );

/**
 * Register style sheet.
 */
function register_plugin_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'statistika', plugins_url( '/statistika/css/style.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'statistika' );
}
```

The paths are good I am sure of it, when I write the URL manually in the browser the style open like any other. The thing I am suspecting the error is the files I am including in the plugin php file. I only included wp-load.php in the beginning. Is that enough for the function wp_register_style to work? If it`s not that then what is the problem? Please help.

EDIT:
New problem, how to include jquery and javascript files inside the admin side of wordpress. I tried this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', plugins_url('/js/jquery.js', __file__));
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', plugins_url('/js/functions.js', __file__));
```

I added this to the existing function in the answer.

EDIT 2:

Got it, I forgot that wordpress does not like $ as a jquery object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to change `wp_enqueue_scripts` by  `admin_enqueue_scripts`

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'safely_add_stylesheet_to_admin' );

/**
 * Add stylesheet to the page
 */
function safely_add_stylesheet_to_admin() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-style', plugins_url('style_admin.css', __FILE__) );
```

this [tutorial](http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-stylesheets-to-wordpress-correctly) will help you how to add Stylesheets To WordPress Correctly

I wish my answer be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. Just give path of your CSS file.

```
function add_wplink_with_parse_stylesheet() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-style', plugins_url( 'CSS File Path here', ____FILE____) );
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_wplink_with_parse_stylesheet');
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times scripts/styles enqueued are only relevant for specific pages.
To minimize redundant file server calls it is best to perform this action only on desired pages:

```
// Hook enqueue style sheet. 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_my_plugin_styles' );

//Register & Enqueue style sheet
function register_my_plugin_styles() {
    if ( is_page( 'specific-page-name' ) ) {
        wp_register_style( 'my_plugins_style', plugins_url( '/my_plugins_name/css/example.css' ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my_plugins_style' );     
    }
}
```

This would work the same for scripts.
If you want a style/script loaded only on the homepage (front-page), you can use  [is_home()](https://wordpress.org/search/is_home) instead of [is_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/#comment-370).